# .Net Core 1.x projects won't start after upgrading to VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been using VS 2017 for a while now and recently upgraded to VS 2017 15.4 just to see how .NET Core 2.0 looks like. However, somehow all my existing projects which are in .NET Core 1.x would not starts(when I start debugging VS will just start and exit right away). When I change the target framework of this projects to .NET Core 2.0 then they do compile and load fine.

Now, there not sure if it is a known bug but there has to be a way for any version of VS to be backward compatible and this version of VS to load and run older versions of .NET Core. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior after installing higher version of .NET Core SDK. Hosting executable `dotnet.exe` will always select highest installed version by default.

.NET Core provides fine grained control mechanism allowing to chose which version of .NET Core should be used by application. Control mechanism is based on `global.json` files which are used to set version of .NET Core for directory in which they are placed and all subdirectories. Settings from higher level global.json files can be overriden using lower level global.json files and new settings will apply to directory in which file is placed and all subdirectories.

Example of global.json file content follows:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.4"
  }
}
```